# Telephone Words problem

Tags: algorithm

Please help solve this:

Telephone numbers are often given out as a word representation, so that they are easy to remember. For example if my number is **4357**, the text given is **HELP**. There could be many other possibilities with the same digits, most of which do not make sense.

Write a space-and-time-optimal function that can, given a phone number, print the possible words that can be formed from it.

Comment: What is the question? Why should we write this function?

Comment: I am looking for suggestions (algorithm) to approach the problem, if not the exact solution.

Comment: Words means 'meaningful' words or any combination of characters?

Comment: You seem to be confusing "help solve" and "Do this for me". [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @Brian - the 'help' is intended towards ideas and not the 'code'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the detailed explanation in the comment this should be a simple permutation combination problem:
Each digit will have a number of characters associated to it (example 4 could mean either of G,H or I) and then for a combination of digits the permutation can be computed.

Comment: appreciate your response, as opposed to the votes to 'close'. this is the extent (provide hints) i expect folks to answer, if they wish to. Of course, more details are always welcome!