# What is the Big-O complexity for this "Telephone Words" Algorithm?

Tags: ruby, algorithm, loops

This isn't homework, just an interview question I found on the web that looks interesting.

So I took a look at this first: [Telephone Words problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7540877/telephone-words-problem) -- but it seems to be poorly worded/created some controversy. My question is pretty much the same, except my question is more about the time complexity behind it.

You want to list all the possible words when given a 10-digit phone number as your input. So here is what I have done:`

```
def main(telephone_string)
  hsh = {1 => "1", 2 => ["a","b","c"], 3 => ["d","e","f"], 4 => ["g","h","i"], 
         5 => ["j","k","l"], 6 => ["m","n","o"], 7 => ["p","q","r","s"], 
         8 => ["t","u","v"], 9 => ["w","x","y","z"], 0 => "0" }
  telephone_array = telephone_string.split("-")
  three_number_string = telephone_array[1]
  four_number_string = telephone_array[2]
  string = ""
  result_array = []
  hsh[three_number_string[0].to_i].each do |letter|
    hsh[three_number_string[1].to_i].each do |second_letter|
      string = letter + second_letter
      hsh[three_number_string[2].to_i].each do |third_letter|
        new_string = string + third_letter
        result_array << new_string
      end
    end 
  end

  second_string = ""
  second_result = []
  hsh[four_number_string[0].to_i].each do |letter|
    hsh[four_number_string[1].to_i].each do |second_letter|
      second_string = letter + second_letter
      hsh[four_number_string[2].to_i].each do |third_letter|
        new_string = second_string + third_letter
        hsh[four_number_string[3].to_i].each do |fourth_letter|
          last_string = new_string + fourth_letter
          second_result << last_string
        end
      end
   end
end
  puts result_array.inspect
  puts second_result.inspect
end
```

First off, this is what I hacked together in a few minutes time, no refactoring has been done. So I apologize for the messy code, I just started learning Ruby 6 weeks ago, so please bear with me!

So **finally** to my question: I was wondering what the time complexity of this method would be. My guess is that it would be O(n^4) because the second loop (for the four letter words) is nested four times. I'm not really positive though. So I would like to know whether that is correct, and if there is a better way to do this problem.

Comment: Your estimate is way off. Given a number of length n, the size of the output can be 4^n.

Comment: Oh I see, that makes more sense. Do you think there is a better way of doing this, or is it just a permutations problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a constant time algorithm, so O(1) (or to be more explicit, O(4^3 + 4^4))

The reason this is a constant time algorithm is that for each digit in the telephone number, you're iterating through a fixed number (at most 4) of possible letters, that's known beforehand (which is why you can put `hsh` statically into your method).

One possible optimization would be to stop searching when you know there are no words with the current prefix. For example, if the 3-digit number is "234", you can ignore all strings that start with "bd" (there are some bd- words, like "bdellid", but none that are 3-letters, at least in my /usr/share/dict/words).

Answer (score -1):

From the original phrasing, I would assume that is requesting all of the possibilities, instead of the number of possibilities as output.

Unfortunately, if you need to return every combination, there is no way to lower the complexity below that determined by the specified keys.

If it were simply the number, it could be in constant time. However, to print them all out, the end result depends highly on assumptions:

1) Assuming that all of the words you are checking for are composed solely of letters, you only need to check against the eight keys from 2 to 9. If this is incorrect, just sub out 8 in the function below.

2) Assuming the layout of all keys is exactly as set up here (no octothorpes or asterisks), with the contents of the empty arrays taking up no space in the final word.

```
{
  1 => [],
  2 => ["a", "b", "c"],
  3 => ["d", "e", "f"],
  4 => ["g", "h", "i"], 
  5 => ["j", "k", "l"],
  6 => ["m", "n", "o"],
  7 => ["p", "q", "r", "s"],
  8 => ["t", "u", "v"],
  9 => ["w", "x", "y", "z"],
  0 => []
}
```

At each stage, you would simply check the number of possibilities for the next step, and append each possible choice to the end of a string. If you were to do, so, the minimum time would be (essentially) constant time (0, if the number consisted of all ones and zeros). However, the function would be O(4^n), where n reaches a maximum at 10. The largest possible number of combinations would be 4^10, if they hit 7 or nine each time.

As for your code, I would recommend a single loop, with a few basic nested loops. Here is the code, in Ruby, although I haven't run it, so there may be syntax errors.

```
def get_words(number_string)
  hsh = {"2" => ["a", "b", "c"], 
         "3" => ["d", "e", "f"], 
         "4" => ["g", "h", "i"], 
         "5" => ["j", "k", "l"], 
         "6" => ["m", "n", "o"], 
         "7" => ["p", "q", "r", "s"], 
         "8" => ["t", "u", "v"], 
         "9" => ["w", "x", "y", "z"]}

  possible_array =  hsh.keys
  number_array = number_string.split("").reject{|x| possible_array.include?(x)}

  if number_array.length > 0
    array = hsh[number_array[0]]
  end

  unless number_array[1,-1].nil?
        number_array.each do |digit|
            new_array = Array.new()
            array.each do |combo|
                hsh[digit].each do |new|
                new_array = new_array + [combo + new]
            end
        end
        array = new_array
    end
    new_array
end
```

Comment: I think the OP was asking for `Big-O` notation (maybe more of a CS question), not code.

Comment: Probably. I just included code to help illustrate the reasoning behind the answer.